# how to pass laravel trans strings to vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

In the event that you are developing your software using the Laravel framework and need to use the Vue library, you will face some obstacles, including how to access the files translation system  provided by Laravel .
like how to access `trans('home.var')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Language file like this

```
<messagings v-bind:language="{{ json_encode(trans('messages')) }}"></messagings>
```

then in vue component print like this

```
<h4>{{ this.language.messaging }}</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

1: pass trans as prop in blade normally just you need to encoding with json used json_encode() method :

`<component :trans="{{json_encode(trans('home'))}}"></component>`

2: in vue component page you need to decode json data first and set the translation data in some var :

```
export default {
props:['trans'],
data () {
  return {
     translation:[],
  };
},
created(){
  this.setTranslation()
},
methods:{
  setTranslation(){
     let decoded_trans = JSON.parse(this.trans);
     this.transaction = decoded_trans;
  }
}
```

3: Now you can access laravel trans normaly just be careful because vue will not detect if you call last node or first.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>{{translation.header.login}}</h2> // this line in laravel mean : trans('home.header.login')
  </div>
<template>
```

Finally I recently started learning vue , so this method may have some flaws, but We all strive to benefit :)